# How to get a response from express server about an error using axios in react app

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

I'm using react and express. In react app I want to use axios.post to send the credentials of the user to express server and hopefully receive a response from it. From the response I want to extract message and status. It looks like this:

```
handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    axios
      .post("/api/users/login", {
        email,
        password
      })
      .then(res => console.log(res.data.msg, res.status))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };
```

At the backend I'm using mongoose model to find out if the user already exists in the database.

```
router.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  User.findOne({ email })
    .then(user => {
      if (!user) return res.status(400).json({ msg: "No such user in the DB" });

      bcrypt.compare(password, user.password).then(isMatch => {
        if (!isMatch) {
          return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Wrong password" });
        }

        req.session.userId = user.id;
        res.status(200).json({ msg: "You have logged in" });
      });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log("Error in catch in findOne"));
});
```

If everything goes Ok and there is a user with these credentials in the database, I receive, as expected, message "You have logged in" and status 200 in the console
BUT
If an error occurs I don't get in axios response custom error message such as "No such user in the DB" or "Wrong password" instead I'm getting default error, I guess, it looks like this:

```
xhr.js:166 POST http://localhost:3000/api/users/login 400 (Bad Request)
Login.js:21 Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:17)
    at settle (settle.js:19)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:60)
```

My question is: how can I get my own error messages instead default ones in case anything goes wrong. For example: if the password is incorrect I want to receive this message in axios response "No such user in the DB".

Comment: Isn't the `msg` field you sent back still the custom one?

Comment: It is custom, but I don't receive it in axios response if the password is wrong or the user is not in the database. I just receive this message in the console: xhr.js:166 POST http://localhost:3000/api/users/login 400 (Bad Request)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make axios catch server response:

Modify from `console.log(error)` to `console.log(error.response)` in catch of axios.

The reference: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/960#issuecomment-309287911

---

For custom error handling within react:

Add to your state a new variable `error: null`.
in axios, in `.then(res=> {})` within its block you conditionally throw an error.
For example:

```
.then( res => {
 if(res.status === 400) {throw new Error("your custom message")}
   ...your code...
 })
```

[The syntax of Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) :

> new Error([message[, fileName[, lineNumber]]])

the thrown error will be caught next in `catch`block, which is:

```
.catch(err => this.setState({error:err}))
```

Now the error's content is within `error` object in state.
To access and display your custom message, depending on where you want, it is either:

`this.state.error.message` or `(this.)props.error.message`

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but can you please explain one thing? I was thinking that if for example I use validation like this: ```if (!user) return res.status(400).json({ msg: "No such user in the DB" })``` I can get my custom error message in ```axios.then(res => res.data.msg)``` part. I thought that when I user ```return res.status...``` I end the request and send the response to the front end. How come my custom error appears in .catch part. I guess I missing something about express?

Comment: @madjack99 I'm really happy it worked for you, I learned something too. I don't want to pretend I'm an expert, but from what I know (with react+express+mongoose stack I did briefly), you have to add to your state a variable ```error: null```, and in ```then(res=> {...})``` block, you conditionally throw an error like:  ```if(res.status === 400) {throw new Error "your message")```. It will be caught in catch block next, which is ```catch(err => this.setState({error:err})```, now depending where you want to show it's either ```this.state.error.message``` or ```(this.)props.error.message```